# optimize delete referencing multiple tables

Tags: mysql

We have a table which stores customer addresses. Those addresses are then used in a few other tables throughout the system to associate the address with an order. We want to periodically remove all old addresses which haven't been used on an order in over a year.

```
address table:
id | address | created_at
1  | 1234 Rd | 2011-03-12 12:45:09
2  | 2345 Rd | 2012-04-12 13:39:19
3  | 3456 Rd | 2012-05-12 14:33:12
4  | 4567 Rd | 2014-12-12 15:19:54

customer_order table:
id | address_id | created_at
1  | 1          | 2011-03-12 12:50:00
2  | 2          | 2012-04-12 12:55:00
3  | 2          | 2014-09-12 12:50:00

group_order table:
id | address_id | created_at
1  | 2          | 2012-07-12 19:23:56
2  | 3          | 2012-10-19 14:36:28
```

So we'd want to remove address with IDs 1 and 3 since they haven't been used in an order in over a year. We'll keep address #4 as it was created recently, and #2 was used within the last year, so it shouldn't be deleted.

What I have currently is:

```
DELETE FROM address WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND id NOT IN (
  SELECT address_id FROM group_order WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
  UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT address_id FROM customer_order WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
)
```

However, my address table contains 800000+ rows, customer_order contains 2.5M+ rows, group_order contains 100000+ rows and there is another table which contains a few hundred rows which I'll also need to add in. Therefore the delete takes a long time to execute (the subquery itself returns 400000+ rows in about 4 seconds, but the delete takes much longer).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it as 2 separate queries using PHP to pass the results of the subquery into the outer query (fetch each of the IDs, then *implode* into the *NOT IN* list in the outer query.

I was hoping mysql would be smart enough to see the subquery doesn't depend on the outer query and would therefore just run it once and cache the results, but I guess it was running the subquery for each row from the outer query, therefore leading to the long run time (~4 seconds per subquery * ~800000).